# unexpected echo error in php. I dont know whats wrong in my code it says there is unexpected echo error in my code on line 20

Tags: php, html, conditional-statements

My file "conditionals.php" throws an unexpected error inside the else statement. Here is my code:

```php
$totalcost = $cost*$quantity;
if( $quantity >= 12 ) { echo "Congrats on ordering atleast dozen.
You requested to purchase $ $quantity cookie(s) at $ $cost each.
Therefore your total is $ $totalcost ."; }
else( $quantity < 12 ) {
// here is some unexpected error
echo "The amount is less than a dozen cookies.<br/> 
    You requested to purchase  $quantity cookie(s) at  $cost each. <br/>
    Therefore your total is  $totalcost .";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your `else` statement. It should be `else if`:

```
$totalcost = $cost*$quantity; 

if( $quantity >= 12 ) { 
    echo "Congrats on ordering atleast dozen. You requested to purchase $ $quantity cookie(s) at $ $cost each. Therefore your total is $ $totalcost ."; 
} else if ( $quantity < 12 ) {
    echo "The amount is less than a dozen cookies.
You requested to purchase $quantity cookie(s) at $cost each. 
Therefore your total is $totalcost .";
}
```

Comment: it should probably be only an `else` statement, given that the additional `if` would be redundant

Comment: For what was posted yeah but sometimes these code samples are simiplied for posting here so I kept the op's exact logic.